# Getting days between two dates using momentjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to implement a validation, the validation is basically for covid doses between two dates.
so for example, if a person takes a job say today he/he she wont be allowed to take another dose for the next 3 months, basically any month or date selected in between will throw and error.
I tried using moment inBetween fucntion, but somehow, it is throwing incorrect result.
this is what i am trying to do.

```
 if (moment(18-10-2022, 'DD-MM-YYYY').isBetween(18-01-2023, 'DD-MM-YYYY'))) {
      setIsDateError({error: true,message: 'Date of administration of First dose cannot be after the Date of administration of Second Dose in Covid Vaccination Tab'})
  return;
  }
```

so validation will trigger as the date lies in between.
any help will be appericated.

Answer (score 0):

The call to isBetween is invalid in your implementation. isBetween takes 4 arguments.

1. Start date - You can pass a string or a moment object.
2. End date - You can pass a string or a moment object.
3. unit :- 'year', 'month', 'week' and few more.
4. inclusivity parameters - '()','[]','(]','[)'

Please refer :- https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/05-query/06-is-between/ for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Check the below code. It may be helpful for your problem.

```js
var startDate = moment("15/02/2022", "DD/MM/YYYY");

var endDate = moment("20/02/2022", "DD/MM/YYYY");

var testDate = moment("15/02/2022", "DD/MM/YYYY");

testDate.isBetween(startDate, endDate, 'days', true); // will return true

testDate.isBetween(startDate, endDate, 'days', false); // will return false
```

Answer (score 0):

`isBetween`takes at least the start and the end of the date range.
This snippet for example works:

```js
console.log(moment('2022-10-30').isBetween('2022-10-17', '2023-01-17'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.4/moment.min.js"></script>
```